# "Link wrapper" for '#theme_wrappers'?

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I would like to build a render array, where the children html is wrapped in a link element.

I am looking for something similar to `'#type' => 'container'` to achieve this. So it would translate to e.g. `'#theme_wrappers' => ['link_wrapper']`.

E.g. like this:

```
$link_element = [
  '#type' => 'link_wrapper',
  '#url' => $url
  'content' => $inner_element,
];
```

The resulting html would be something like this:

```
<a href="..">
  <div>Inner content</div>
</a>
```

The important thing here is that the contents should be a render array, and not merely a '#title' property. This also means I don't want any filtering and escaping. The content, once rendered, should be treated as html.

In Drupal 7, I wrote my own element type and theme wrapper for this, [themekit_link_wrapper](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/themekit/tree/themekit.theme.inc#n32).

For Drupal 8, I am wondering if something like this already exists.

Or if not, how I would port my D7 'themekit_link_wrapper' to Drupal 8.
(In the end I might answer this myself)

Comment: Use inline template or prefix and suffix.

Comment: Note that your example for themekit in D7 is inaccurate, `#type` should be `themekit_link_wrapper` and `#url` should be `#path`.

Comment: If you are referring to the example code in this question, it was not meant to use themekit_link_wrapper. Instead, it is showing a not-yet-existing imaginary element type.

Comment: @IvanJaros If such a thing does not already exist, I rather make my own dedicated #type than using #prefix/#suffix or inline template.

Comment: I don't think that's time-wise. You will have to tell Drupal to print raw content one way or the other. Using inline template is safe, quick and perfectly fine solution. Not to mention, no template file or theme function is needed. But YMMV.

Comment: @IvanJaros If you want you can post an answer showing how it would work with inline template. I don't think I will use it myself, but maybe others are interested who have the same problem.